# Prometheus logical operators

Tags: prometheus, promql

I am trying formulate a query to Prometheus. Assume there are three queries A, B and C. I need to return result of B if A>0, else return result of C.

While trying this I found some unusual behavior i.e if doing `(1 and 0)` it's giving 1 and if doing `(0 and 1)` it's giving 0. Why?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to answer your question why will be to cite official documentation about [matter](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#logical-set-binary-operators):

> `vector1 and vector2` results in a vector consisting of the elements of `vector1` for which there are elements in vector2 with exactly matching label sets. Other elements are dropped. The metric name and values are carried over from the left-hand side vector.

So in fact query like `vector(1) and vector(0)` will return 1, since when executing this query first `vector(1)` is executed, and then all it results are checked for existence of metrics with the same label set (in this case empty) in result of `vector(0)`. And for the case of `vector(0) and vector(1)` they are changing their roles.

Regarding query you are looking for, in simplest case you'll need query

```
B and A>0 or C
```

Here `A>0` will return any result only if result of A is positive, and thus results of B will be filtered accordingly.

Please notice, that this is a simplified version, that will work if all three queries return metrics with the same labels sets. If no, you'll need to adjust it with additional `on` or `ignoring` clause. [Read more about vector matching](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#vector-matching).